# Connect Android App to AWS Cloud(RDS, DYNAMO DB etc.)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, cloud, amazon-rds

Currently I am storing my Android application data in  SQLite (local DB) but I want to connect my application with AWS cloud. How i can connect my application with cloud and Which one is good Database for my app. My application is related to IoT where I will using MQTT Data.

Comment: AWS has full-scale IoT services that you can find here: https://aws.amazon.com/iot/. You should take a few tutorials on this topic, such as Greengrass (https://aws.amazon.com/greengrass).

Answer (score 0):

you do not connect you app to AWS RDS database.
You should create some server (SpringBoot for example) which will talk with you RDS.
The server should have API endpoints and they will serve your application.
Take a look what mean to crate REST API